# Подключить на разных страницах разные js

Tags: checkbox, html, javascript

Подскажите, можно ли подключить на разных страницах сайта (статичные страницы на 1с-битрикс) разные библиотеки и коды js скриптов в head?
Сложилась проблема что их очень много на главной и страницах 2 и 3 уровня, и идёт конфликт, хочу попробовать решить проблему таким образом, чтобы не переделывать пол верстки.
Пока писал пришла идея сделать примерно так в шапке сайте (обязательное условие что коды должны быть именно в шапке)
1 идея

```
if( is_page(http://site.ru/) )  
        include 1.js,2.js; 
    else
       include 3.js,4.js;
```

2 или использовать стрение страницы

```
<html>
<head> 
</head>       
<body>

<head> 
</head>

<body> 
</html>
```

Comment: @нгш

> попробывать

**попробовать**

    include 1.js,2.js;

Зачем? Предпочтительным способом включения скрипта всегда был и будет `<script>`.

    <head> 
    </head>       
    <body>

    <head> 
    </head>

    <body>

Это вы где такое видели?

---

Ответом на впорос будет - да, подключать скрипты по условию, только не инклюдом.

Comment: если не инклудом, тогда чем?
PS не помню где, на каком то сайте смотрел строение хтмл и увидел такую конструкцию, что самое интересное, но она работает о_О

Comment: @нгш, я же написал - `<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/file.js"></script>`

Comment: @Fike т.е так include <script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/file.js"></script> ???

Comment: @нгш **не надо include**  просто

echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/file.js"></script>'